# PowerShell DataSet -- array trimming and export to CSV

Tags: powershell, dataset, export-to-csv

I'm having some problem extracting values from this function:

```
function Get-DatabaseData {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [string]$connectionString,
        [string]$query,
        [switch]$isSQLServer
    )
    if ($isSQLServer) {
        Write-Verbose 'in SQL Server mode'
        $connection = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    } else {
        Write-Verbose 'in OleDB mode'
        $connection = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
    }
    $connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
    $command = $connection.CreateCommand()
    $command.CommandText = $query
    if ($isSQLServer) {
        $adapter = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $command
    } else {
        $adapter = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter $command
    }
    $dataset = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.DataSet
    $adapter.Fill($dataset)
    return $dataset.Tables[0]
}
```

So, basically this function runs a query against a database. However, the returned value has this irksome "number of records returned" as the first element. Example:

```
> Get-DatabaseData -connectionString $myConnString -isSQLServer -query $myQuery_PlanCache
6

CacheType                 : Prepared
Total Plans               : 118
Total MBs                 : 10,406250
Avg Use Count             : 41
Total MBs - USE Count 1   : 3,343750
Total Plans - USE Count 1 : 33

CacheType                 : Proc
Total Plans               : 53
Total MBs                 : 8,015625
Avg Use Count             : 118
Total MBs - USE Count 1   : 2,617187
Total Plans - USE Count 1 : 10

-- additional records snipped --
```

I tried replacing `return $dataset.Tables[0]` with the following:

```
    $dbdata = @($dataset.Tables[0])
    $dbdata = $dbdata[1..($dbdata.Length-1)]
    return $dbdata
```

But I still get that irksome first item of "6".

In addition, the output refuses to be marshaled into a CSV file using `| Export-Csv`

How do I truncate/remove the first item? And how can I marshal the leftover data into a CSV file?

BTW, `$PSVersionTable` returns:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      4.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.34209
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.16406
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is this line:

$adapter.Fill($dataset)

Which returns the number of items provided to the method. Try changing it to:

[void] $adapter.Fill($dataset)

Therefor the caller of `Get-DatabaseData` receives that number (i.e. 6) + `$dataset.Tables[0]`